# Horizontal ScrollView removes textView unless in portrait mode

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, horizontalscrollview

I have a horizontal ScrollView with several textViews nested inside. I am populating the textViews via mysql database, Im getting strange results when i rotate my screen to landscape, the text appears, but in portrait mode, only some of the text appears and the horizontal scrollbar disappears. I could use some help figuring this one out.

layout_xml

```
<LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <HorizontalScrollView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:paddingStart="10dp">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tvBlue"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="25dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_margin="3dp"
                            android:scrollHorizontally="true"

    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
                            android:paddingStart="8dp"
                            android:paddingEnd="8dp"
                            android:text="Blue Package"
                            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tvOrange"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="25dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_margin="3dp"
                            android:scrollHorizontally="true"

    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
                            android:paddingStart="8dp"
                            android:paddingEnd="8dp"
                            android:text="Orange Package"
                            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tvOandB"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="25dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_margin="3dp"
                            android:scrollHorizontally="true"

    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
                            android:paddingStart="8dp"
                            android:paddingEnd="8dp"
                            android:text="Orange and Blue Package"
                            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </HorizontalScrollView>
            </LinearLayout>
```

Adapter.Java Class

```
if (slingchannel.getBlue().equals("1")){
    view.tvBlue.setText("Sling Blue Package");
} else if(slingchannel.getBlue().equals("0")){
    view.tvBlue.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

if (slingchannel.getOrange().equals("1")){
    view.tvOrange.setText("Sling Orange Package");
} else if(slingchannel.getOrange().equals("0")){
    view.tvOrange.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
if (slingchannel.getOandb().equals("1")){
    view.tvOandB.setText("Sling Orange and Blue Package");
} else if(slingchannel.getOandb().equals("0")){
    view.tvOandB.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Like I said, only some of the text appears, but if i rotate to landscape it all shows, then rotate back to portrait and some of the text is gone. When I rotate back to portrait mode, the text disappears.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by Setting the text and instead of trying to add the text, i just set visibility to visible when the condition was met.